# Construct a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Construct a matrix for which N(A) = all combinations of (2,2,1,0) and (3,1,0,1).

My answer is a 4 by 4 matrix:
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -2 & -3\\
    0 & 1 & -2 & -1\\
    0 & 0& 0& 0\\
    0 & 0& 0& 0
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
Can anyone check my answer is correct nor not?

Comment: Please have a look at this to learn how to typeset your matrix: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023

Comment: Do you mean : Construct a $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$ so that null space of A equals $\text{span}\{(2,2,1,0),(3,1,0,1)\}$  ?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR The question doesn't specify the shape of this matrix. In fact, this is what I want to ask, since the solution gives me a 2 by 4 matrix.

Comment: @YaoZhao Yes, this is correct. You don't need the last two rows, but you're not wrong to include them either. You could add arbitrarily many rows of zeroes.

Comment: @Théophile Okay, thanks! By the way, I find -2, -2, -3, -1 are just inverse numbers of the original solution. Is this common rule?

Comment: @YaoZhao Do you mean the original solution gives
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 2 & 3\\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}?$$
That doesn't make sense... you can see that $A(2,2,1,0)^T$ and $A(3,1,0,1)^T$ are non-zero.

Comment: @Théophile no, the original solution is correct. Just delete two last rows of my matrix. My question is the numbers shown in the both matrix, -2, -3, -2, -1. They are just to put '-' before all combinations of (2,2,1,0) and (3,1,0,1).

Comment: @YaoZhao Oh, I understand now. (I think you meant "original matrix", not "original solution".) Certainly there is a connection: if you carry out the multiplication, then the $+2$ cancels with the $-2$, etc. This is happening because the matrix happens to have a nice structure: $(1,0,\ldots)$ and $(0,1,\ldots)$. In other words, the property you're noticing is related to the matrix being in RREF. Consider, however, that you could add to the matrix any linear combination of these two rows, like $(10,2,-24,-32)$.